# Using vendored OpenBLAS as a dependency in a CMake project

Tags: cmake, openblas

I have OpenBLAS checked out as a Git submodule in `thirdparty/OpenBLAS`. With

```
add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/OpenBLAS")
```

in `CMakeLists.txt` it successfully configures and builds. But

```
target_link_libraries(encoder_sample fused_transformer OpenBLAS::OpenBLAS OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

fails to find the target:

```
Target "encoder_sample" links to target "OpenBLAS::OpenBLAS" but the target
was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

If it matters, I am using Visual Studio 2019 with WSL. I expect that I am missing something trivial, just can't figure out what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are configuring and building OpenBLAS as part of your CMake project, the `IMPORTED` target `OpenBLAS::OpenBLAS` is not available. The imported target is defined by the `OpenBLASConfig.cmake` configuration file, typically used in conjunction with `find_package(OpenBLAS ...)` command, after you have **installed** OpenBLAS on your machine. In your case, you can use the OpenBLAS CMake target *directly*, as defined their CMake files.

Assuming your OpenBLAS repository is similar to [this](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS) GitHub repo, the CMake target is defined [here](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/blob/b6a948fbee9688d6bc3eb31a10f95895d4d97491/CMakeLists.txt#L171):

> ```
> set(OpenBLAS_LIBNAME openblas${SUFFIX64_UNDERSCORE})
>
> ...
>
> add_library(${OpenBLAS_LIBNAME} ${LA_SOURCES} ${LAPACKE_SOURCES} ${RELA_SOURCES} ${TARGET_OBJS} ${OpenBLAS_DEF_FILE})
> ```

So the target name you want to use will be `openblas` or `openblas_64`, depending on your target architecture. So for a 64-bit build, you can try this:

```
 target_link_libraries(encoder_sample fused_transformer openblas_64 OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```