# CMAKE target link to a local openblas folder

Tags: cmake, openblas

I do not have Openblas installed. I do not want to install it. I want CMAKE to build my project using a local copy of OpenBLAS. I read this SO post: [Using vendored OpenBLAS as a dependency in a CMake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60862235/using-vendored-openblas-as-a-dependency-in-a-cmake-project)
Based on that, I made my CMAKELists.txt below:

My CMAKElists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(Eigentest main.cpp)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Libraries/eigen-3.4.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fsanitize=address -O3 -fopenmp -march=native")

add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Libraries/OpenBLAS-0.3.21")

target_link_libraries(Eigentest openblas_64)
```

I do get this output from CMAKE:

```
[...]
-- /home/user/Desktop/untitled/cmake-build-debug/Libraries/OpenBLAS-0.3.21/lapack/CMakeFiles/dtrti2_LU.c
-- /home/user/Desktop/untitled/cmake-build-debug/Libraries/OpenBLAS-0.3.21/lapack/CMakeFiles/ctrti2_LU.c
-- /home/user/Desktop/untitled/cmake-build-debug/Libraries/OpenBLAS-0.3.21/lapack/CMakeFiles/ztrti2_LU.c
-- c lapack
-- Building deprecated routines
-- Building Single Precision
-- Building Double Precision
-- Building Single Precision Complex
-- Building Double Precision Complex
-- Generating openblas_config.h in include/openblas
-- Generating cblas.h in include/openblas
-- Copying LAPACKE header files to include/openblas
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/Desktop/untitled/cmake-build-debug
```

When I compile my project, I get this error:

```
FAILED: Eigentest 
: && /usr/bin/c++ -fsanitize=address -O3 -fopenmp -march=native -g  CMakeFiles/Eigentest.dir/main.cpp.o -o Eigentest  -lopenblas_64 && :
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenblas_64: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I link to a **local** copy of openblas? I want to link to it without installing it.

Comment: The openblas target is named as `openblas_64` only when during the configuration you got the [message](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/blob/v0.3.21/cmake/system.cmake#L70) `Using 64-bit integers.`. Otherwise the target is named as `openblas`. You could also check existence of the target with `if(TARGET openblas_64)`.

Comment: If the targets aren't imported from the subdirectory (i.e. when they aren't exported, which is usually done within the install step) then the `if(TARGET openblas_64)` would still be false. I think this is a case of not importing the targets. But I might be wrong. Either way an entire CMake / make log would help debug this issue further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can provide you only with a wild guess because you haven't provided the entire make log:

Normally when you `add_library` CMake configures the entire path for any targets that link against it. Judging by what's passed to `/usr/bin/c++` **this isn't happening**. I assume it's mostly because the targets from `add_subdirectory` are only available for the local scope of that given subdirectory `CMakeLists.txt`.

To quickly test this out try to **add the target** in your **root** `CMakeLists.txt` file with the `IMPORTED` tag (after the `add_subdirectory`, i.e.:

```
add_library(openblas_64 SHARED IMPORTED)

#OR

add_library(openblas_64 STATIC IMPORTED)
```

Then proceed with the `target_link_libraries(...)`

Thus your `CMakeLists.txt` should look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(Eigentest main.cpp)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Libraries/eigen-3.4.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fsanitize=address -O3 -fopenmp -march=native")

add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Libraries/OpenBLAS-0.3.21")

add_library(openblas_64 SHARED IMPORTED)
#OR: add_library(openblas_64 STATIC IMPORTED)

target_link_libraries(Eigentest openblas_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you link against `openblas_64` and CMake decides to do just `-lopenblas_64` it probably didn't find a target by that name.

You can run `cmake --build . --target help` to get a list of all targets defined in your project, there should be at least one for openblas and that's what you need to pass to `target_link_libraries()`.